# Blackberry Mobile Business Object not getting updated with the RFC changes

Tags: blackberry, sybase

I've created a Blackberry Mobile Business Object (MBO) which is mapped to an SAP RFC.
Now the RFC has been modified (an extra parameter added) but my MBO is not reflecting the changes.

I'm trying to re-map the attributes of the MBO but it is not showing me the newly added parameter. I'm using SUP 2.0.

Please advise.

Regards,
Nitin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to disconnect the SAP Profile that has created for ur SAP Server,then connect and import the RFC, u will be able to see the RFC updated with all the changes.

Try it out and update here....